# Configure Azure WebJob SDK logger filter

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

## Background

Building a WebJob with `.net core 7` and `Webjob SDK`, found there are too many prints from `Azure.Core` and tried to filter it, it work with code but failed with configure, would like to make the logging configurable via configure files/environment variable

## What's worked

```cs
builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
{
    b.AddConsole();
    b.AddFilter("Azure.Core", LogLevel.None); // this work
});
```

## What's not work

Copied the appsettings below from some web app template and it is not working

```
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "None",
          "Azure.Core": "None"
        }
    },
```

Tried to use `AddConfiguration` but not sure am I doing the right thing.

```cs
builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
{
    b.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration); // this line
    b.AddConsole();
});
```

## Full code

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorageQueues();
        });
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            configurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConfiguration(context.Configuration);
            b.AddConsole();
        });

        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current configuration, the `AddConfiguration` method is used to load configuration settings, but it may not directly apply to the logging configuration.

- To configure the logging with the desired filters, you can explicitly access the logging section from the configuration and apply filters.

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "None"
    }
  }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorageQueues();
        });
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
        {
            configurationBuilder
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
        {
            // Load logging configuration from appsettings.json
            var loggingConfiguration = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");
            loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(loggingConfiguration);

            // Add console logging
            loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
        });

        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

- I've removed the explicit use of AddFilter. Instead, we rely on the configuration loaded via AddConfiguration to apply the filtering for "Azure.Core" based on the configuration present in the appsettings.json.

Comment: Thanks for the code tried `context.Configuration["Logging"]` myself and not working `GetSection` do the trick, tested with `GetSection` and `AddConfiguration` the filter should work and no `AddFilter` needed, please edit the answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: Thanks @Bill Using `GetSection` and `AddConfiguration` should handle the filtering without the need for an explicit `AddFilter`