# WebJob - supress logs for Azure Queue connection

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-storage-queues, webjob

After upgrading my WebJobs to dotnet 7 everything is working pretty fine, but now it shows logs for connecting to Queues like this:

[image]

This is being shown everytime the job checks for new messages (5 sec). After this, it's impossible to check on the logs that I really need.

How can I hide these logs and see just the ones I really need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your code and configuration.

Comment: Are you checking locally or in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially even I got the same logs with all the Requests from `Azure.Core` package.

```cs
 Azure.Core[1]
      Request [****] GET https://harshu**.queue.core.windows.net/queue/messages?numofmessages=16&visibilitytimeout=600
      x-ms-version:2018-11-09
      Accept:application/xml
      x-ms-client-request-id:****
   --------
```

- The reason for this is configuring the logging in     `Program.cs` file to add all the console logs.

```cs
 builder.ConfigureLogging((context, log) =>
 {
     log.AddConsole();
 }
```

- To avoid this, you can add the logging level in `appsettings.json` file to ignore the logs from `Azure.Core` package.

I have taken references from this [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77577391/configure-azure-webjob-sdk-logger-filter) configuration.

***With Configuration Logging level in `appsettings.json` file:***

***`appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Azure.Core": "None"
    }
  },
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=harshu**;AccountKey=*****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}
```

***`Program.cs` file***

```cs
  builder.ConfigureLogging((context, log) =>
  {    
      var logconfig = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");
      log.AddConfiguration(logconfig); 
      log.AddConsole();
  });
```

****OR****

***With AddFilter option:***

Can add a filter in `program.cs` file itself.

```cs
  builder.ConfigureLogging((context, log) =>
  {           
      log.AddConsole();
      log.AddFilter("Azure.Core", LogLevel.None);
  });
```

***Output:***
[image]

Comment: Once check with this configuration from your end and let me know.

Comment: b.AddFilter("Azure.Core", LogLevel.Error);
Worked like a charm for me... thanks a lot...